# Adding water to stack of glasses

Tags: python, algorithm, math, graph-algorithm, pascals-triangle

I always wanted to know if there is any real-world application of Pascal's triangle than just coefficients of the binomial expansion.

I tried to solve this problem:

[image]

[image]

But, What if I am adding K units of water and wants to find a glass which has the least water in it:

Where, Glass will be found as:   `c`-th glass in `r`-th row

And I believe. If we could find this then it will not be difficult for us to find amount of water in any glass for which `{i<r and j<c}`

- Problem:

  **Input**
  Water added- K units and capacity of each glass as 1- unit

  **Output Expected** : `c` th glass in `r` th row having least water in it.

I tried to solve problem by keeping note of capacity of each row when it starts overflow:
and wants to know how to keep going with this method.

```
      1       max = 1, cap = 1
     1 1      max = 1, sum(coefficients)=2**1 = 2, cap = 2/1 
    1 2 1     max = 2, sum = 2**2, cap = 4/2 = 2 units 
   1 3 3 1    max = 3, sum = 2**3, cap = 8/3 units
  1 4 6 4 1   max = 6, sum = 2**4, cap = 16/6 units
```

#Not sure but this is how it seems to me for the rate @which water is being added.

```
                 1
              1/2   1/2
           1/4   2/4  1/4
        1/8   3/8    3/8   1/8
     1/16  4/16  6/16   4/16  1/16
```

Should I use 2-D list and define as :

```
Δ1, Δ2 = 0, 0
if g(n-1, k)>1 and k <= n-1:
    Δ1 = g(n-1, k) -1 
if g(n-1, k-1)>1 and k-1 <= n-1:
    Δ2 = g(n-1, k-1) - 1
g(n, k) = Δ1/2 + Δ2/2
```

`g(n,k) = g(n-1, k-1) + g(n-1, k)`

```
g = [[0]*(i+1) for i in range(11)]
def f(g, K):
    g[1][1] += 1
    K = K-1
    d1, d2 = 0, 0
    for n in range(2, 10):
        for k in range(1, n+1):
            if k ==1:
                g[n][k] = g[n-1][k]/2
            if k == n:
                g[n][k] = g[n-1][k-1]/2
            else:
                if g[n-1][k-1]>1:
                    d1 = g[n-1][k-1] -1
                if g[n-1][k] > 1:
                    d2 = g[n-1][k] -1
                g[n][k] = d1/2 + d2/2        
    return g, K
k = int(input())
while k:
    g, k = f(g, k)
for x in g:
    print(x)
```

I don't know what is missing?

Comment: *"I tried to solve problem by keeping note of capacity of each row when it starts overflow"* Be careful, some glasses might start overflowing before other glasses in the same row.

Comment: @Stef Yes! glasses with max value of the row.(median type)
2 for even & 1 for odd.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Exactly! I'm looking for the answer of question described in word. Glass with the least water?
The image was something from where I thought, "How can I find the least water glass."

Comment: @DarshanPatil so you just want to know the glass with the least water?

Comment: The middle glass will always have the most water. The outer edges will always have the least.

Comment: @rajah9 I don't think so, consider K = 6, the least glasses is at R = 4 & C = 2 or 3, which is the middle glass

Comment: @shole yes, not middle always I took `10` units of water got R = 5, C = 2, 4 as 1/16
Maybe wrong it's by hand.

Comment: @shole, for K=6, my (by hand) sketch says R4C1 = 0, R4C2 = 1/4, R4C3 = 1/4, R4C4 = 0. Since 0 < 1/4, isn't R4C1 (and R4C4) the least amount of water in that row?

Comment: @rajah9 Yes I have got same but shouldn't be empty. R4C1 = R4C4 = 0 and R4C2 =R4C3 = 1/4

Comment: @rajah9 if you said so but I auto guessed OP of coz omit 0 by some...sense? besides, if 0 is accepted then answer is always 0, as there is infinite many glasses

Comment: When the OP said "which has the least water in it" I thought he meant the minimum of any row, `r` , that had started to fill. I was thinking the `min(r)` where RrC1 could be 0. But it looks like the OP might be defining *least* to be *smallest positive* rather than *smallest greater than equal to 0*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such small `K` constraint simple row-by-row filling is enough (we can store only two rows, here 2D list is used for simplicity)

```
def fillGlasses(k, row, col):
    gl = [[k]]
    level = 1
    overflow_occured = True
    while overflow_occured:   # also can stop when at needed row
        print(gl[level-1])  #before overflow
        level += 1
        overflow_occured = False
        gl.append([0]*level)
        for i in range(level - 1):
            t = gl[level-2][i] - 1
            if t > 0:
                gl[level-1][i] += t/2
                gl[level-1][i+1] += t/2
                gl[level-2][i] = 1
                overflow_occured = True
    #print(gl)  #after all
    return gl[row-1][col-1]

print(fillGlasses(21,8,4))

[21]
[10.0, 10.0]
[4.5, 9.0, 4.5]
[1.75, 5.75, 5.75, 1.75]
[0.375, 2.75, 4.75, 2.75, 0.375]
[0, 0.875, 2.75, 2.75, 0.875, 0]
[0, 0, 0.875, 1.75, 0.875, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0.375, 0.375, 0, 0, 0]
0.375
```

Comment: few changes to your code could give me answers.

Answer (score 0):

I presumed you are asking this exact online judge question, or a very similar one: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/champagne-overflow2636/1

If so, actually the constraints for `R` and `C` is only 500 and any simulation could work. One little catch is that there maybe water in a row even previous row is not fully filled. You may consider small test cases and simulate to find out, for example `K = 6`, the glasses will look like:

```
1
1, 1
0.75, 1, 0.75
0, 0.25, 0.25, 0 
// Notice previous row is not fully filled, makes sense as "middle" glasses will overflow faster
```

I think for implementation-wise it is similar for top-down and bottom-up approach. Here is my top-down accepted code which simply simulate the water pouring and overflow process, with C++, same algorithm can be implemented in any language:

```
class Solution {
    public:
    double cups[505][505];

    void pourWaterAt(double K, int R, int C, int targetR){
        if(R > targetR) return;
        cups[R][C] += K;
    
        if(cups[R][C] > 1){
            double overflow = cups[R][C] - 1;
            cups[R][C] = 1;
            pourWaterAt(overflow/2.0f, R+1, C, targetR);
            pourWaterAt(overflow/2.0f, R+1, C+1, targetR);
        }
    }

    double waterOverflow(int K, int R, int C) {
        memset(cups, 0, sizeof(cups));
        pourWaterAt(K, 1, 1, R);
        return cups[R][C];
    }
};
```

After the simulation, you can just scan through `cups[R][C]` and find the smallest positive one (and its index) to get the answer.

Comment: Thanks! It's a good one but I'm trying to find glass with the least water in it.

Comment: @DarshanPatil I have edited the answer a bit, actually same code /algorithm works, you just need to scan through the 2D array and get the smallest positive one after the simulation.

Comment: Could you provide the same in python?